# Deleting is now breaking working show actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Deleting a List works, however, when I clicked on the shopping lists after deleting a list breaks the show action for the rest of the lists below them? These were working before I added a delete action.

Coming from this URL http://localhost:3000/lists

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListsController#show
>
> Couldn't find Product with 'id'=7

List_controller (condensed)

```
    def show
        @list = List.find(params[:id])
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end
    def destroy
        @list = List.find(params[:id])
        @list.destroy
        redirect_to lists_path, notice: 'List was deleted.'
    end
```

Show Lists

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', list_path(list), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

List.rb

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :products, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

Should also delete Child/Associated Products included in the list.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list, optional: true
  has_one_attached :hero
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag(:h1, "Listing All Shopping Lists") %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

  <% @list.each do |list| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= list.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', list_path(list) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', list_path(list), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

Comment: What is the URL in the browser when you see the error?

Comment: Also, what does your show view look like?

Comment: @MarkLocklear many thanks for your response, it is most kind of you. I've updated my original post with the two additional points included. Much appreciated.

Comment: *"Deleting a List works, however, when I clicked on the shopping lists after deleting a list breaks the show action for the rest of the lists below them?"* On what shopping list do you click? Have you pressed the browser "back" button (opening a cashed version of a page) and tried to open the show of the deleted list?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Many thanks for your response, it is valued! I can confirm, I do not hit the back button, as the destroy link redirects back to list with the previous element removed. When I then click any of the first few links at the top (old lists). They present the error. It like the other list product_id's reset upon destroy. As only the 2 or 3 bottom lists (work), however as I delete the lists. Nearly reaching the bottom, those too, become broken.

Comment: Let me quickly describe what I think your scenario is: You are on the `GET /lists/:id` (show) page of list `L1`, you then click the "Delete" button. This will call `DELETE /lists/:id` (destroy) which will successfully remove the list `L1`. After removing the list you are redirected to `GET /lists` (index) which shows an overview of the lists with list `L1` removed. When you then click on list `L2` you are taken to `GET /lists/:id` (show) for list `L2` at which point the exception is raised. Does this description fit your scenario?

Comment: @3limin4t0r thank you for checking, you almost have it. I am on list#index, beside each list I present show and delete links. I click on the delete list, it runs the list#destroy, which refreshes the screen with a flash indicating the list has been removed. Now if I click on the top list item show, it will break with the ID error in my original post. ```    def destroy/ With list has_many :products, dependent: :nullify or :destroy, so I still need to go into my list#destroy and loop through all of the products?

Comment: The exception *"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListsController#show, Couldn't find Product with 'id'=7"* says that you try to to find product with id 7 in your `ListsController#show`. Can you add this controller action to the question, so we might be able to see where/why you try to find this specific product.

Comment: @3limin4t0r absolutely, I have updated the original post with the show and destroy list controller actions. I guess for me the weird thing is that the lists work 100% until I delete them. It might be due to my destroy controller not featuring products, or dependent :destroy or :nullify or even perhaps is it accepts_nested_attributes_for :products?

Answer (score 1):

You have `has_many :products, dependent: :destroy` in your List model. That causes the deletion of all products belonging to this list. You should add dependent: :nullify if you want to keep the products.

I assume you are in the show action of a non existing product.

Comment: many many thanks for the response, it is very much appreciated. Upon revising :destroy to :nullify. I get a new error ```ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation in ListsController#destroy
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "list_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:``` Could accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true be a solution?

Comment: to make :nullify work, I believe I need to add a migration to Products, list_id column_options: { null: true }. Is that correct? Are there any unintended consequences?

Comment: @dimButTries that's correct if that is what you want to achieve. For unintended consequences you could check for database integrity issues. When products are not shown anywhere in your application anymore they will take up unnecessary space in your database that could slow down any queries on the products table. Perhaps any nil errors could occur if you reference to a non existing list from a product.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone for your intervention - I am enamoured by the SO community!

The issue was in my list controller#show 
from

```
    def show
        @list = List.find(params[:id])
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end
```

to

```
    def show
        @list = List.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I think this is something to do with the hidden id attribute which follows you around. The product :id was in conflict with the list :id in this action.

I am not sure why this error manifests itself when you delete an item.

However, removing it works.

Comment: I was just about to ask why you use `@product = Product.find(params[:id])`. The id given is a list id, so it makes no sense to try to find a product with a provided list id. If you need the products you can use the association `@list.products`. Glad you've solved the issue though. +1 for posting your solution, and not letting SO in the dark.